# How to connect android phone with other hardware through bluetooth?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect the android device with other hardware through Bluetooth. The application is connecting to other phone but it is not connecting to hardware. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what type of other hardware you want to connect to, but see this android controlled robot project writeup for an explanation of how to connect to a bluetooth serial module.

http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1398

Comment: BluetoothDevice device =mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

Comment: try {
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});           
BluetoothSocket tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1); 
btSocket=tmp;
//btSocket =device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Not created1"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Socket creation failed.", e);
}
try
{
btSocket.connect();
Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: BT connection established, datatransfer ");
}catch (IOException e) {}..I m using this code i face the connection refused exception

Comment: pls give some solution is there need to set baud rate ..If so how